# Generalising Cutting lens changes intensity of light of image

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

We were told that if I cut a (say biconvex lens) in half, my intensity of light which forms the image is now half.I was wondering if there was a general formula for if I cut a lens horizontally (a variable,say 2/3 of the aperture),what intensity of light would I receive for the image formed?

Comment: The intensity of light in the image is equal to the intensity on the lens. Cut the lens in half, only half of the light will hit the lens and will reach the image. The intensity of the image is proportional to the area of the lens

Answer (score 0):

In terms of reducing intensity, there is no difference between adding an aperture to the lens (in front of it or behind it) or cutting out pieces of the lens. In a sense a cut lens is just an ordinary lens with a different type of aperture. In any case, the intensity is proportional to the area of the aperture/remaining lens.

As an interesting side note, the focused parts of the image would stay the same shape as before cutting. Defocused parts would have blur spots with the shape of the remaining lens, like in these two images (taken from here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bokeh), instead of circular as with a whole lens (assuming the lens is circular, of course):

[image: Shapes of defocus]

Maybe this helps visualise what's happening here: you're cutting off pieces of the image each object point makes. When the image is sharp, you don't see the shape because its size reduces to a point. But the shape is still there and you've still cut off pieces of it, removing those pieces' contribution to intensity.